# Alternative for read lines using less memory JAVA

Tags: java

Good morning,

I am progarmming a tool to get some information from log files, the problem is that that files could by 100Mb, 300Mb ...900Mb.

When I run my application using log of 100-200Mb the program works fine, but when I use a 500Mb or above log the application send heap space problem.

The problem could be this line?

```
List<String> resultado = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(ruta.getText()));
```

I think that this object consume a lot of memory and it is the cause of my problem

There is a best way to read line by line the file and storing in a List consuming less memory?

Thank you very much

Comment: you cannot "store it in a list, consuming less memory", instead you have to get rid of this need, but process (&forget!) them line/chunk wise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is a best way to read line by line the file and storing in a List consuming less memory?

Not really, no.

The problem is the "store it in a list" aspect.   That is the fundamental reason why you are using lots of memory.  Any time you hold an entire file in memory in `String` form you are going to use lots of memory<sup>1</sup>.

The solution is NOT to store the entire file in memory at the same time.  Instead, read it line by line, process each line as you read it, and then discard the lines.

For example, instead of this:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(somePath);
for (String line: lines) {
    // process line
}
```

... do this:

```
try (BufferedReader br = ...) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        // process line
    }
}
```

---

<sup>1 - You may save a bit of space by storing the file contents as bytes, but with recent JVMs and their more space-efficient `String` representations, the saving won't be great enough to make a lot of difference.</sup>

Comment: It works! now, using BufferedReader  I can proces the log files without heap space errors.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, `Files.readAllLines` reads all the lines to the memory;

In my case I got a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` error on a **~5GB** text file with **~2M** lines.

You can use `Files.lines` instead, which reads the lines as `Stream` rather than as `List`.

E.g.

**To count the lines in large file, use this (since Java8):**

```
// Don't use this (memory inefficient):
// return Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filePath)).stream().count();
// Use this instead:
return Files.lines(Paths.get(filePath)).count();
```

@see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-